# why I can't update a variable value and return self.func(*args)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm sending a variable value from `programa1`  for a new object using :

```
def send_price(self):
    self.pricesend = float(self.text1.get()) #this take a value from a tkinker.Entry
    print(self.pricesend)
    objetoprograma1.Object(self.pricesend)
```

the object  "objetoprograma1" return a new value using:

```
class Object():

    def __init__(self, price):

        self.price_recibe = float(price)
        print(self.price_recibe)

        self.new_price = self.price_recibe + 10
        print(self.new_price)

        programa1.Aplication.recibe_newprice(self, float(self.new_price))
```

now I want to update the value in the `principal1` `tkinter.Entry` called `self.text1`:

```
def recibe_newprice(self,  new_price):

    self.new_price = new_price
    print("price new recibe" , self.new_price)

    ## this don't work.. this don't update or change the value in the tkinter.Entry

    self.text1.delete(0, len(self.text1.get()))
    self.text1.insert(self.my_main, str(self.new_price))
```

I have the following exception:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "B:\MAESTRIA\PYTHON\trabajos\hello\programa1.py", line 38, in send_price
    objetoprograma1.Object(self.pricesend)
  File "B:\MAESTRIA\PYTHON\trabajos\hello\objetoprograma1.py", line 19, in __init__
    programa1.Aplication.recibe_newprice(self, float(self.new_price))
  File "B:\MAESTRIA\PYTHON\trabajos\hello\programa1.py", line 51, in recibe_newprice
    self.text1.delete(self.my_main, len(self.text1.get()))
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'text1'
```

the full `programa1.py`

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
import tkinter
import objetoprograma1
import time

class Aplication():
    def __init__(self,my_main):
        self.my_main = my_main
        self.variables()
        self.GUI()

    def variables (self):
        self.price = None
        self.list = []

    def GUI(self):

        self.text1 = tkinter.Entry()
        self.text1.insert(0, "1000")
        self.text1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

        self.boton1  = tkinter.Button(self.my_main, text = "sendprice", command = self.send_price )
        self.boton1.grid(column=1, row = 0)

    def send_price(self):
        self.pricesend = float(self.text1.get())
        print(self.pricesend)
        objetoprograma1.Object(self.pricesend)

    def recibe_newprice(self,  new_price):

        self.new_price = new_price
        print("price new recibe" , self.new_price)

        ## this don't work

        self.text1.delete(0, len(self.text1.get()))
        self.text1.insert(self.my_main, str(self.new_price))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tkinter.Tk()
     #root.geometry("800x500+0+0")
    root.title("titulo")
    app = Aplication(my_main=root)
    root.mainloop()
```

and `objetoprograma1.py`

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
import programa1
import tkinter
import time

class Object():

    def __init__(self, price):

        self.price_recibe = float(price)
        print(self.price_recibe)

        self.new_price = self.price_recibe + 10
        print(self.new_price)

        programa1.Aplication.recibe_newprice(self, float(self.new_price))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your Object class and look at the exception message. You are calling the `recibe_newprice` method, but passing it the `Object` instance (Object has no text1 attribute). The `recibe_newprice` is written for the `Aplication` class and as such expects `self` to be an instance of the `Aplication` class. You seem to be mixing up what classes are for or how the `self` argument works.

My first tip is to name things with more descriptive names. Names like `Object`, `Application`, and `Program1` don't tell the reader anything about what the purpose of those objects are.

Second, do you know the difference between classes and functions? Maybe this will help. I would code the `send_price` method this way:

```
def send_price(self, price_recibe):
    pricesend = float(self.text1.get())
    print(pricesend)
    print(price_recibe)

    new_price = price_recibe + 10
    print(new_price)
    self.recibe_newprice(new_price)
```

If this doesn't make sense why I'm doing things this way or why this might be considered better/easier than the way you did it then I suggest researching how python classes, attribute assignment, and argument passing works.

Comment: mr daveydave400  ... thanks for answere....  but this don't work....  anyway   I don't want and I don't need join both files .... I have another program with more code and the same problem....  ...  may be do you have another ideas in order to fix this?? thanks

Comment: @yhoyo - I think daveydave400 was suggesting a better way of implementing just one of your methods, but to be honest you need to rethink, re-design and re-write all of your code, as you seem to completely misunderstand the role of objects, methods & functions.

Comment: @yhoyo, @TonySuffolk66 is correct. I was trying to be nice, but you seem to misunderstand everything about how arguments are passed; especially when it comes to classes/objects and the `self` argument (which is automatically passed with instances of a class).

Comment: And why I rewrote that method was because the way you are using classes (specifically your `Object` class) is wrong. Classes don't work that way.

Comment: @daveydave400   and TonySuffolk66  thanks for your answere...  After some research I understand why you told me about that.... thanks for all